# Oracle decode equivalent function to Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, case

So, I'm in migrating database from oracle to Postgres, and this is my error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function decode(unknown, unknown, integer, unknown, integer, unknown, integer, unknown, integer, unknown, integer) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

and here's my code :

```
sqlQuery.append(" order by ");
            sqlQuery.append(" decode('pts.process_status', 'PTSPS_INPROGRESS', 1, 'PTSPS_SUBMITTED', 2, ");
            sqlQuery.append("            'PTSPS_DRAFT', 3, 'PTSPS_REJECTED', 4, 'PTSPS_APPROVED', 5) ");
```

do you have any clue?

From what I've read, some say to replace the decode function with COALESCE, but I don't have any idea how the syntax is.

Comment: **but i dont have any ide how the syntax is**. There are NO detours in professional life. If you are tasked to do this migration, then it is *your* job to learn what it is necessary to make it happen. Say someone tells you what you should do ... and then it turns out, it was wrong, and some corrupts some of your data. What will you tell your boss later on "i didnt read the documentation, i just wrote down what some dude on the interwebs told me to" ... do you really think that is a good approach? Meaning: you absolutely should learn "enough" so that you are able to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a standard `case` expression:

```sql
order by case pts.process_status
    when 'PTSPS_INPROGRESS' then 1
    when 'PTSPS_SUBMITTED'  then 2
    when 'PTSPS_DRAFT'      then 3
    when 'PTSPS_REJECTED'   then 4
    when 'PTSPS_APPROVED'   then 5
end
```

Comment: i tried this, and now my error : 
ERROR: column "pts.process_status" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: @WildanVEP: this relates to another part of the query, which you did not show in your question - so I can't really tell. You might want to ask a new question for this, providing your entire query to start with.

Answer (score 2):

Postgres has a shortened form of the logic using arrays:

```
order by array_position(array['PTSPS_INPROGRESS', 'PTSPS_SUBMITTED', 'PTSPS_DRAFT', 'PTSPS_REJECTED', 'PTSPS_APPROVED'],
                        pts.process_status
                       )
```

I should note that the `CASE` solution suggest by GMB is standard SQL and works in both Postgres and Oracle (and pretty much any other database), so this is just a shortcut.